# module pandas has no attribute 'day_name'

Tags: python, pandas, module

I want to know the day names from a column of dates, but I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'day_name'
```

I thought it was a problem with my pandas version, so I upgraded it and Python stopped working in my laptop. I reinstalled everything and Python didn't work, and I thought that the latest windows update ruined my Python, so I switched to Linux Mint and I still get the same error. I also checked my pandas version (which I got from anaconda) and it says:

```
pandas           : 1.0.1
```

According to the pandas doc this function is *New in version 0.23.0.*, but mine is more recent than that. Any ideas on how to solve this guys? this very confusing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`day_name` is a method on `Series.dt` (or [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day_name.html)), rather than `pandas` or `pd`, as I assume you have tried to call it (`pd.day_name`?).

The example in the documentation is:

```
>>> idx = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', freq='D', periods=3)

>>> idx
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

>>> idx.day_name()
Index(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'], dtype='object')
```

Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) for more details.

A further short example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"mydate": ["2012-01-01", "2013-01-01"]})                     
df.mydate = pd.to_datetime(df.mydate)                                           
print(df.mydate.dt.day_name())
```

Output:

```
0     Sunday
1    Tuesday
Name: mydate, dtype: object
```